# How many ways to put $n$ distinct objects into $k$ distinct boxes so that none of the boxes are empty?

Tags: combinatorics

I have $n$ distinct objects. I have to put them into $k$ distinct boxes so that none of the boxes are empty. For example if $n=2$ and $k=2$ ans$=2$; if $n=3$ and $k=2$, ans$=6$.

Comment: So you are looking for the number of surjections $\{1,\ldots,n\}\to\{1,\ldots,k\}$?

Comment: Yes i am looking for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are told to count the number of surjections $f:\>[n]\to[k]$. This is one of the famous *twelve ways*, i.e., a standard problem.

Any such $f$ induces a partition of the set  $[n]$ into $k$ nonempty *blocks*. The number of these partitions is the so-called *Stirling number of the second kind* ${\cal S}(n,k)$. There are recursions and tables for these numbers, but they cannot be represented in terms of simple binomials, or similar.

Given such a partition we can allocate the values $1$, $\ldots$, $k$ to the individual parts in $k!$ ways. It follows that the number you are after is $\>k!\,{\cal S}(n,k)$.

Comment: thanks a lot, sir.

Answer (score 0):

If $k <n$. The number of total maps from $\{1,2,..,n \}$ to $\{1,2,...,k \}$ is $k^n$ and number of non onto map is $k{(k-1)}^n$ because we can choose k-1 object from k object in k ways. And now we have to add $\frac{k(k-1)}{2}{(k-2)}^n$ because when we removed an object from the range set, it is counted again when we are removing different set because we are taking all maps.
So the number of onto map should be $k^n-k{(k-1)}^n + \frac{k(k-1)}{2}{(k-2)}^n-.... + (-1)^{k-1}k{(k-(k-1))}^n$.
If $k > n$ then no maps are onto.
If $k = n$ then $n!$ will be number of onto maps clearly.

Comment: The answer for n=5,k=3 is 150 your formula gives 147

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @Santo I corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

As Lord Shark the Unknown stated in the comments, the problem is equivalent to finding the number of surjections from $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots, n\} \to \{1, 2, 3, \ldots, k\}$.

Clearly, the answer is $0$ if $k > n$.  Let $k \leq n$.

The number of functions $f: \{1, 2, 3, \ldots, n\} \to \{1, 2, 3, \ldots, k\}$ is $k^n$ since each of the $n$ elements in the domain can be assigned to one of the $k$ elements in the codomain.  From these, we must exclude those assignments in which one or more of the elements in the codomain is excluded from the range.

There are $\binom{k}{j}$ ways to exclude $j$ of the $k$ elements in the codomain from the range and $(k - j)^n$ ways to assign each element in the codomain to one of the remaining $k - j$ elements in the codomain.  By the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), the number of surjections $f: \{1, 2, 3, \ldots, n\} \to \{1, 2, 3, \ldots, k\}$ is 
$$\sum_{j = 0}^{k} (-1)^j\binom{k}{j}(k - j)^n$$

Note that this answer is equivalent to the one provided by Christian Blatter since 
$$S(n, k) = \frac{1}{k!}\sum_{j = 0}^{k} (-1)^{k - j}j^n$$